# Inequality to prove Jensen+Minkowski

Tags: measure-theory, inequality

How can I prove the following inequality?
Let $X$ be a positive random variable and $m$ an positive integer.

$\mathbb{E}\left((\int_{a}^{b}X_{s}ds)^{m}\right)\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}\mathbb{E}(X_{s}^{m})^{\frac{1}{m}}ds\right)^{m}$.

I guess I shall use Jensen and Minkowski inequality, but Iam not able to do the proof.

Comment: It might help to rewrite the inequality as 
$$
\left[ \mathbb{E}\left((\int_{a}^{b}XdP)^{m}\right)\right]^{1/m}
\leq \int_{a}^{b}\mathbb{E}(X^{m})^{\frac{1}{m}}
$$

Comment: thx for your response, but Iam still not able to prove it.

Comment: I have edited the question, because there was a mistake. I really don't know how to apply Minkowski for this inequality.

Comment: I think I got it: It is based on the integral version of Minkowski inequality right? And Jensen is not necessary at all.

Comment: What does $X_s$ mean please?

Comment: $(X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ is a stochastic process.